# ListView how to make some columns Read-only

Tags: asp.net-3.5

I am replacing a Gridview with a ListView as I needed Insert functionality. My DAL has all the code set up for Insert, Update, Delete & Select.

When I put my datasource in the ListView properties, it created a the templates for me in the aspx files. 
However, expect for the Primary Key filed all fields are editable. I did change the Textbox to a lable & changed #Bind to #Eval. I get an run-time error. It caomplains about not finding a Update function with required parameters. It is passing all the fileds as parameters to my Update function.

My column structure is
MainID, SubID, Name, Size.

My SQL statement is
UPDATE table1 SET Name = @Name, Size = @Size WHERE (MainID = @original_MainID)

1. In my DAL, I have a UPDATE function that updates only Name & Size based on MainID. How can I make SubID read-only & not pass it to my Update function?
2. I need to add a dropdownlist for the column Name. The dropdownlist needs to be bound to another SQL table. Can this be done?